# ArcMap losing selection of asset features?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, select

I am currently working through asset updating and wondering why this is happening.

Scenario: I've selected more than 50 of the same feature class poly-lines. Now I edit to add photo numbers from an adjacent photo table window to the poly line feature class. I get through anywhere from 1-5 of these photo numbers entered before ArcMap deselects my features.

Then I have to re-select all of my polylines and scroll to where I left off. ArcMap 10.5.1 has not been this time consuming until now.

Is this software or hardware related?

Comment: Are you saving your edits at any point?  Saving edits deselects features in ArcMap (no idea why!).

Comment: You could try making a layer from selected features (right click on the layer then choose Selection::Create Layer from Selected Features which will make a new layer containing only those ones.. do your edits as normal and if they unselect right click on the selection layer and use Select::Select All  to select them all again; when you're done simply remove the selection layer (right click and choose Remove) to dismiss it and the edits will be safely done to the base table.